# My Feature depends on a module. Do I have to specify that module's dependency, as well?

Tags: 7, features

My Feature depends on Views. Views has a dependency on Ctools. Do I have to specify Ctools as a dependency in my feature as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ctools calls in your module, then you should declare it as a dependency. Otherwise no need.

Answer (score 1):

As general advice, declare the dependency from the modules for which your module needs to access their functions, or classes.

In the specific case, even if you know that the Views module requires the Chaos tool suite module, and your module needs both, it is better to explicitly declare both as module's dependencies.
The difference is just a line more (`dependencies[] = ctools`) in the .info file, but that doesn't create problems to Drupal. Adding that line is also less error-prone: Suppose that your module doesn't depend from the Views module anymore; if you didn't have that line, and you don't add it, the module would not work correctly for who install it, as it would be enabled even if the Chaos tool suite module is not present. It also help if you are developing a version of that module for Drupal 6; in Drupal 6, the View module doesn't declare the Chaos tool suite module as dependency. If you declare just the dependency from the Views module your module would not work if it uses a function the Chaos tool suite module.

Similar thing can be said for modules that depend from Drupal core modules, which are required from Drupal itself. As Drupal 8 shown with the Node module, those modules could not be anymore required from Drupal, and there could be profiles where the Node module is not required. If a module depends from it, but it doesn't declare it as dependency, it would not work in Drupal 8 without to change its .info file.

Comment: now I'm am really confused. your answer contradicts paul-m's completely. what to do? :(

Comment: I am not contradicting paul-m.